# How to find out which country an email address originated from?

Tags: gmail

I am trying to find out where an email I received, originated from.  The sender has a gmail account but I am interested to find out which Country it was created in.

Comment: There are some commercially available finders. Not sure how far it'd yield accurate results! And there are no ways to find countries of e-id with the resources that an email application provide.

Comment: You won't be able to determine this from a provider like Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, Apple.  Where the sender was when they sent the email isn't an indication where it was created in.

Answer (score 3):

You can find that the with simple geo lookup or timezone map option where you can find the location of the sender with the IP address in the header.

You are having options like:

**Option A: Gmail may include the IP Address**

Gmail doesn’t include the IP address of the sender when the sender is using Gmail’s web interface to send email. However if he or she is using a desktop client (like Microsoft Outlook) or a mobile device to send that email, the IP address is often included in the outgoing message.

Open the message in Gmail, click on More – > Show Original and search for the line “Received: from “ – it may have the IP address of the sender that you can map to a physical location with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

[image]

**Option B: Find the Sender’s Time Zone**

When the IP address is not available, you can determine the sender’s very-approximate location from the time-zone of the originating computer. Go your Gmail Labs page and enable the “Sender Time Zone” feature.

Now open any message in Gmail and click on the down arrow that says time zone details. Please check the same link below for further details.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-location-of-gmail-sender/21098/

added

Option B: Find the Sender’s Time Zone

When the IP address is not available, you can determine the sender’s very-approximate location from the time-zone of the originating computer. Go your Gmail Labs page and enable the “Sender Time Zone” feature.

Now open any message in Gmail and click on the down arrow that says “Show details”. The message will display the the current time in the sender’s time zone as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Next you can use this timezone map to determine countries where the current time is the same as the time displayed in the Gmail message. Obviously this not the most foolproof method as two different countries can be in the same time zone but when the IP address is not available in Gmail, this is the closest you can get.

On a related note, the time zone of your outgoing Gmail messages is determined from your computer’s time zone. If you would like your Gmail messages to show a different time zone, just go to your computer’s data and time settings and change the time zone.

Comment: You really should pull the relevant information from your url.

Comment: was a good answer I just lazily added a chunk from the url more usefully,  with pics.  lest that url goes down.